# PHP Sessions and Cookies

Tags: php, mysql, session, cookies, session-cookies

I have a log in page which opens a profile page.Now when a user logs in the session is set.But i have not provided log out facility yet.So I can very well open the log in page and log in as a different user , without the sessions and cookies being destroyed.My question is when i log in the second time , which session does the browser use the previous one or the one which has been recently created.The profile page checks whether session is set or not.Can we have two sessions simultaneously for the same website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup i agree with you SAM.
usually session user set for one user in one browser, and it will be automatic destroy by second user when login in same browser. I think it will be more configuration if you want two session with same value. for example facebook and twitter used one session simultaneously. 
may be if you don't want destroy first session when second user login you can make function to check session is used or not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can have two or more sessions you have to create with different names.

```
$_SESSION['user1']="some value";
$_SESSION['user2']="some value";
```

but if you are making only one session the new value will overwrite the previous one.

But it doesn't make sense why you want to login with 2 users simultaneously. You should provide more information.